# How to write plus-minus sign in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax, help-suggestion

[image: Plus-on-up and minus-on-down]

Plus-Minus. Means a quantity of same magnitude can have either a positive or a negative value. As commonly found in square roots such as

$$\sqrt[2]{625}= +-25$$.

Here is an [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) SVG-[example](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9fd0e29038fc2e47a77371066a8cf60f01cc00b1) of a basic trigonometry formula:

[image: sin theta equals to plusminus Sqrt over whole 1 minus cos square theta].

How to render it using MathJax?

........................................................................

ALSO;

Also I've seen use of minus-plus, i.e. [image: minus-plus].

I can't remember specific example but it was probably in some chemistry related text, in a situation; two variables (say $x$ and $y$) each have positive and negative value. But if $x$ is positive then $y$ is negative, and if $x$ is negative then $y$ is positive.

Don't know whether the second one is standard or not; but if the second-one is standard or allowed in MathJax; how to use it in MathJax formatting??

................................

PS. I've gone through [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also seen Google but could not find.

Comment: `\pm` and `\mp`

Comment: Great. You should publish it as answer and I'm accepting it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry didn't see your comment before I posted my answer

Comment: It is in the tutorial, point 12.

Comment: @quid Can't find there. Mentioned in PostScript.

Comment: Accepted as duplicate "*that solved my purpose*". But It is quite hard to find there. it has been also mixed up with division sign.

Comment: It's alright you asked the question. I agree it's not that easy to find there. I still feel it should be closed as dupe for systematic reasons. Down the road your Q will still serve as useful sign-post for future user having had the same problem.

Comment: [Detextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is helpful for this and similar questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use
$$
\pm
$$
or
$$
\mp
$$
That is

> \pm

or

> \mp